# How to prevent user from navigating to other pages in javascript silently (without confirmation dialogbox)?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, preventdefault

I want to somehow prevent the user from navigating to other pages in javascript (silently without any comfirmation dialog).
I tried to do this with:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

OR

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
   return false;
}
```

OR

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
   return;
}
```

none of the above codes works. Except that the second example, displays an confirmation box.

The Problem is I want to prevent this silently (without any dialogboxes), like nothing has happened.

Comment: You won't be able to do it silently

Comment: This is a bad idea. Users can disable JavaScript to sidestep this.

Comment: If you're trying to trap someone on your page, you can't. That said, if you want to prevent someone from following any links on your page, you could always change them all to point to nowhere. Ie. `href="#'`

Answer (score 0):

To display warning text to the user before the close:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) 
{
    return 'You are about to close the page. Are you sure you want to do this?';
};
```

That said, you can't prevent a user from moving away from your site. That would be a security nightmare. Also, the user can always close the browser.